# Making a call to my webservice via curl doesn't work

Tags: web-services, post, curl, get

I have a simple function to test my webservice via `POST` like this:

```
  function service(){
    $service_url = 'http://example.com/example_endpoint/user';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    $header = array(
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    $curl_post_data = array(
      "name" => "name_test",
      "mail" => "name_test@example.com",
      "pass" => "123",
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($curl_response);
  }
```

The webservice is specting the parameters on the array and the Content-Type is suppoused to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but when I run the function in my browser and check the "Network" tab on "inspect element", there is a call to my webservice via `GET` despite of the fact that I'm setting the option to be `POST`
and the Content-Type keeps on `text/html`

This webservice allows to create users with the parameters inside the array `$curl_post_data`

I use the add-on "Poster" on Mozilla to call my webservice and it's succesfull, but when I call the function above, it doesn't work ¿How could I implement this function to make the correct call?

Answer (score 0):

In Network tab on your browser you will not see POST as curl is posting this. Network tab shows activity from client side (Browser). Your data posting is happening by server through CURL.

Add this code to properly url encode data

```
$curl_post_data_string = '';
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($curl_post_data as $key => $value) {
    $curl_post_data_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
rtrim($curl_post_data_string, '&');
```

And change this line

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
```

Keep in mind to see what you got after hitting a URL in CURL you need to print `$curl_response`

```
echo $curl_response;
```

This is a proper example of posting data using CURL

http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: This call is suppoused to create a new user, sorry I didn't mention that. It's not a call to loggin

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that the POST doesn't show on the NETWORK tab.

Comment: POST is visible on Network Tab when something is posted from client side. Using curl you have posted from server side. Network tab do not shows when a request is made from server side.

Comment: Instead of your `foreach` loop, use $curl_post_data_string = [http_build_query](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)($curl_post_data);